# Detect rotation angle of a line by CNN

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

I want to detect the angle of a line by CNN network. So I create the datasets. The picture size is 64x64. A line with width of 4 pass through the mid-point(32,32). The line angle can be any of 0-180. The task is to input the picture and the CNN output the regressed angle(0-180).

The loss I create is the mean included angle of two lines.(0-90)

The problem is that I can let the train loss and test loss go down any more after the mean included angle loss decrease to 20 degree.

The code is simple and here. `Draw` function make the dataset. `angle_loss2` func is the defined loss.

How to solve this ?

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import cv2
import numpy as np

blackboard=np.zeros([64,64],dtype=np.float64)

def draw(batch):
    tmplist=[]
    lable = torch.randint(0, 180,size=[batch,])
    x0=32
    y0=32
    for id in range(batch):
        angle=lable[id]
        x1=x0-100*np.cos(angle)
        x2=x0+100*np.cos(angle)
        y2=y0-100*np.sin(angle)
        y1=y0+100*np.sin(angle)
        tmp=blackboard.copy()
        p1=(int(x1),int(y1))
        p2=(int(x2),int(y2))
        # p1=(int(x0),int(y0))
        p2=(int(x2),int(y2))
        cv2.line(tmp,p1,p2,1,4)
        tmp=torch.from_numpy(tmp)
        tmp=torch.stack((tmp,tmp,tmp))
        tmplist.append(tmp)

    return torch.stack(tmplist),torch.tensor(lable,dtype=torch.float)



class AngleNet(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1=nn.Sequential(nn.Conv2d(3,64,2,2),
                                 nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Conv2d(64, 128, 2, 2),
                                 nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Conv2d(128, 256, 2, 2),
                                 nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Conv2d(256, 64, 2, 2),
                                 nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 )

        self.dense=nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(64*4*4,40),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(40,2),
        )

    def forward(self,input):
        x= self.conv1(input)
        x=x.view(-1,64*4*4)
        x= self.dense(x)
        return x


def angle_loss2(res,angle):
    res[res>180]=180
    res[res<0]=0
    tmp=torch.abs(angle-res[:,0])
    tmp[tmp>90]=180-tmp[tmp>90]
    return torch.mean(tmp)


optimizer=torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters())

for batch_id in range(5000):
    train_batch,lable_batch=draw(50)
    res=net(train_batch.float())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss = angle_loss2(res,lable_batch)
    print(loss)
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
    if batch_id % 50==0:
        train_batch, lable_batch = draw(20)
        res = net(train_batch.float())

        torch.set_printoptions(2,sci_mode=False)
        res[res>180]=180
        res[res<0]=0
        tmp = torch.abs(lable_batch - res[:,0])
        tmp[tmp >90] = 180- tmp[tmp > 90]
        print(tmp)
```

Comment: Could you explain why you are trying to predict two angles, aren't they both related?

Comment: Neural nets are great for classification, not for quantification. You can bin angles into groups, and classify images into these groups, but you cannot measure the angle of a line. Instead, use the CNN to detect the line that you want to measure, then apply regular math to compute the angle.

Comment: *Neural nets are great for classification, not for quantification* @CrisLuengo, what's wrong with regressing the angle directly?

Comment: @Ivan Have you seen anybody doing that successfully? Producing precise measurements? Would love to learn how they accomplished that.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Depth estimation would be an example. The model is learning to regress the distance from the camera corresponding to every pixel in the image.

Comment: looks like you are simply drawing a straight line as your input, then why do you need a neural network to "detect", rather than simply use traditional way to calculate the angle?

Comment: @Guang It's just a task when I play with the CNN.  I know many traditional methods can easily solve this.

Comment: @Cris Luengo Yes, I have also changed  the problem to a 180 classes classification problem, it achieved nearly 80% acc. The problem is that if the line is not simply pass through midpoint, but start from the midpoint（like a ray） , the network can easily predict the angle of the ray.(0-360) by regressing the cos and sin value. So why a line's angle can't be predicted ?

Comment: @Ivan That is far from my interests, so haven’t seen that. Do you have a reference? Is that from a single frame, or a depth from stereo thing?

Comment: yf s, you’re asking the wrong person.

Comment: There are many depth estimation models out there, the basic principle is for the model to predict a dense map at one-to-one or a lower resolution. The model can be supervised with various functions such as L1, L2, Huber, berHu losses. These work with single images (Single Image Depth Estimation). Other methods are self-supervised and rely on temporal consistencies, such as Monodepth Godard *et al* and SfM-Learner Zhou *et al*. These methods require monocular sequences or stereo vision.